# Superposition of cylinder stress and normal stress

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, applied-mechanics, statics, strength

I need to calculate the principal stresses for the given cylinder with thick walls inside filled with gas shown on this picture:[image]

I used the Lamé equations, namely:

$$\sigma_{x} = p\cdot\frac{r_{1}^2}{r_{2}^2-r_{1}^2}$$

and

$$\sigma_{r,\phi} = \sigma_{x}\cdot[1\mp(\frac{r_{2}}{r})^2].$$

I got the 3 stresses, namely: the axial, the radial and the circumferential stress.

Also I have 2 moments acting on the cylinder.

I calculated the normal stress, which I will denote as $\sigma_{xn}$ as follows:

$$\sigma_{xn} = \frac{M_{y}}{I_{y}}\cdot z$$

or actually:

$$\sigma_{xn} = \frac{M_{y}}{I_{p}}\cdot z$$

$$I_{p} = (d_{2}^4-d_{1}^4)\cdot\frac{\pi}{32}.$$

I calculated the normal stress and everything is fine until now. But now I have 4 stresses total, namely the 3 from the Lamé equations and 1 normal stress. I have to calculate the principal stress on the points A and B on the picture.

I know that I have to use the superposition principle to add the stresses together, but I don't know how.

Is there some sort of equation like:

$$\sigma_{1,2} = \frac{\sigma_x + \sigma_r}{2} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{\sigma_x - \sigma_r}{2}\right)^2 + \tau_{r\phi}^2}$$

for this task?

How to add the stresses when they are all of different nature?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the moments bending or torque with respect to the cylinder?

Comment: I don't think I quite understand your question, but on the cylinder we have the inside pressure and 2 moments that are bending the cylinder.

Comment: I meant bending or torsion, see my comment under my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple load cases of the same structure with the same supports, you can calculate elastic stress components for each load case separately and then simply add the resulting stresses to get stress for all the loads acting together. Adding the stresses is straight forward, you just have to be careful about coordinates or directions. Stress at a point is tensor with respect to specific orientation, so if you need to add 2 stress tensors (by components), they both need to be in the same coordinates.

In your case, principal Lamé stresses will be in cylindrical coordinates (axial, radial, circumferential) and the principal stress from bending moments would be only in axial direction (if the moments are torque, you get shear circumferential/axial shear stresses), so you would be adding only axial stress components.

When in doubt, just write down the whole stress tensors from both loads in the same coordinates and add their corresponding components.

Comment: So the axial stress from the Lamé equations $\sigma_{x} = p\cdot\frac{r_{1}^2}{r_{2}^2-r_{1}^2}$ is acting in the same "way" as the $\sigma_{xn} = \frac{M_{y}}{I_{p}}\cdot z$ and I can add them together?

Comment: @User198 Essentially yes, although I am a little bit confused by your nomenclature, since you seem to be using second polar moment of area $I_p$, rather than second moment of area, which would be just a half of that ($I_p = I_y+I_z$). Polar moment is associated with resistance to torsion, whereas simple second moment of area is associated with resistance to bending. So if the moments are bending, you should use $I_y = I_z = \frac{\pi}{64}\left(d_2^4-d_1^4\right)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Alright. It seems I got confused a bit. Will use  $I_y = \frac{\pi}{64}\left(d_2^4-d_1^4\right)$ instead. Thanks also for answering the main question.